# How to correctly use Contentful Typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, contentful

I have been trying to get Typescript to work using contentful JS library. The documentation is unclear and there are no good examples which show it working in practice. Even the "demo video" code doesn't compile.

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/typescript-in-javascript-client-library/

Could someone please help me understand what the type definitions should be in this example using contentful client js?

Issues I'm facing are mostly related to "contentful_id" not existing in the returned entries, key fields like sys.id not being in the interface or not being able to use returned fields as strings.

```
    export type SiteConfigurationSkeleton = {
      contentTypeId: "siteConfiguration",
      fields: {
        handle: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        analyticsId: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        globalCallout?: contentful.EntryFields.RichText,
        menuId?: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
      }
    }
    
    export type SiteConfiguration = {
      fields: {
        handle: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        analyticsId: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        globalCallout?: contentful.EntryFields.RichText,
        menuId?: contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Text,
      }
    }
       

 
     /**
     * Fetch the site configuration from Contentful.
     * @param handle The handle for the site configuration from Contentful
     * @returns 
     */
    async function getSiteConfigurationByHandle(handle: string): Promise<SiteConfiguration> {
      const client = getClient();
      const entries = await client.getEntries<SiteConfigurationSkeleton>({
        content_type: "siteConfiguration",
        "fields.handle": handle,
        include: 3,
      });
    
      if (!entries.items.length) {
        throw new Error('Site Configuration missing, please check for a site configuration entry in contentful')
      }

      // what is the entry type in this example?
      // I've tried wrapping it in contentful.Entry<SiteConfiguration> but that leads to 
      // other issues with field types not working.
 
      const siteConfiguration = entries.items[0]
    
      return siteConfiguration
    }
```

Comment: I've found explicitly setting undefined in the Entry generic seems to coerce it to a usable type: 
export interface SiteConfigurationFields {
  contentTypeId: "siteConfiguration",
  fields: {
    handle: EntryFieldTypes.Text,
    analyticsId: EntryFieldTypes.Text,
    globalCallout?: EntryFields.RichText,
    menuId: EntryFieldTypes.Text,
    defaultLocale: EntryFieldTypes.Text
  }
}

export type SiteConfiguration = Entry<SiteConfigurationFields, undefined>

Answer (score 0):

I initially tried manually creating my own types to represent my content model in Contentful, but I quickly found that to be pretty painful because of the kinds of issues you're describing.  Basically, the response from Contentful contains a lot more "internal stuff" than what you define in your content model, i.e. what you know about, and A) you need to use it, but B) it's hard to account for in the strongly-typed way that makes TypeScript shine.

I worked around all of this by giving up and incorporating the automatic type generator [cf-content-types-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cf-content-types-generator) into my build process.  I have it set up so that whenever I run a full debug build, scripts go out and query Contentful to get my content model schema and then feed the JSON file from that into the type generator.  The type generator then creates the TypeScript files that define interfaces for the objects in my content model.  Those autogenerated files get checked and the autogeneration doesn't run in production.

Almost by definition, every build system is strange and customized, so I'll just include a few of the highlights of what I've got working in my Windows and MSBuild-based system...

From package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "contentful": "^10.2.3",
    "contentful-cli": "^2.6.22",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cf-content-types-generator": "^2.12.2",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "contentful-export": "contentful space export --config contentful/export-config.json --management-token %CONTENTFUL_MANAGEMENT_PAT% --space-id %CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID%",
    "contentful-typegen": "cf-content-types-generator contentful/export.json --v10 --out types/contentful",
    "contentful-typegen-help": "cf-content-types-generator --help",
    "contentful-update": "npm run contentful-export && npm run contentful-typegen"
  },
}
```

You'll notices that the parameters in the scrips above set the locations of the various input and output files for the autogeneration process.

From pre-build.cmd:

```
if "%buildConfig%"=="Debug" (
    echo Running pre-build actions for %buildConfig%
    call UpdateModels.cmd
) else (
    echo No pre-build actions for %buildConfig%
)
```

From UpdateModels.cmd:

```
IF EXIST "SetEnvironment.cmd" (
    ECHO SetEnvironment.cmd exists
    CALL SetEnvironment.cmd
) ELSE (
    ECHO SetEnvironment.cmd not found. Skipping refresh of Contentful models.
    goto EOF
)

call npm run contentful-update

:EOF
```

The file SetEnvironment.cmd is a local-only file (i.e. git ignored so that secrets don't checked in) that sets the environment variables that the npm scripts need to access the necessary space in Contentful.  This is what causes the process to only run in debug mode.

So, the caveats here are that I've got a small project with a small content model (only 5 files autogenerated *.ts files in the output) so I'm not sure how well this approach scales out.  That said, it runs quite quickly and is well worth the small amount of increased build time during development.